# firebase is returning null user even when the user has not logged out

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I am using "firebase": "^8.2.0" in my react project.

When a user logs in I store the token in local storage and, before making any API call to the backend, I check the expiration time of the user and based on that returns the token. If the token is expired then I call
`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {}))` to get the new user and stores the token in localstorage again.

Here is my code :

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import {firebaseConfig} from "./config.js"
    
// Initialize Firebase    
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = firebase.auth();

export const getToken = (cb, val) =>
  new Promise((reslove, reject) => {

    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

    if (token) {
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      const expiration_time = decoded.exp * 1000;

      var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

      //checking if token is expiring in 10s
      if (expiration_time - currentTime > 10000) {
        reslove(token)
        return;
      }
    }

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      console.log("userAuth",userAuth); 
      console.log("refresh token ", userAuth?.refreshToken);
      if (userAuth)
        userAuth
          .getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
          .then(function (idToken) {
            localStorage.setItem("token", idToken);

            reslove(idToken);    
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            reject()
          });
    });
  })

export default firebase;
```

Everything works fine with this flow but after few days if user tries to login then userAuth is comming as null because of which token is null.

I don't know why does it work only for few days.

Comment: Instead of describing the flow of your approach, please edit your question to show the [exact, minimal/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will drastically increase the chance that someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication auto-caches the ID token and then refreshes it in the background about 5 minutes before it expires.

That seems quite similar to what you're trying to do here. As far as I can tell your force-refresh of the token 10s before it expires should never trigger, and is not going to accomplish anything anyway.

You should be able to call `getIdToken()` (or `getIdToken(false)`) in the code that needs the token, instead of implementing your own expiration/refresh mechanism.